# Is it mandatory to use df.unpersist() after using df.cache()?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it mandatory to use `df.unpersist()` after using `df.cache()` to release the cache memory?
If I store my DataFrame in cache without unpersisting, then the code runs very quickly. However, it takes pretty longer time when I use `df.unpersist()`.

Comment: When RDD is garbage collected, unpersist is automatically called on it.

Comment: @Rumoku: And when RDD is garbage collected?

Comment: It's JVM, so RDD became eligible for garbage collection as soon as there are no more references to this object, isn't it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not *mandatory*, but if you have a long run ahead and you want to release resources that you no longer need, it's highly suggested that you do it. Spark will anyhow manage these for you on an LRU basis; quoting from [the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#removing-data):

> Spark automatically monitors cache usage on each node and drops out old data partitions in a least-recently-used (LRU) fashion.

The `unpersist` method [does this by default](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala#L2959), but consider that you can explicitly `unpersist` asynchronously by calling it with the a `blocking = false` parameter.

```
df.unpersist(false) // unpersists the Dataframe without blocking
```

The `unpersist` method is documented [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@unpersist(blocking:Boolean):Dataset.this.type) for Spark 2.3.0.

Comment: What is the difference between `df.unpersist()` and `df.unpersist(false)` ?

Comment: It means to not wait for all blocks to be unpersisted before returning.

Comment: What do you mean by blocking?

Comment: "Blocking" is the term usually applied to any form of call that returns the control to the caller after it has performed the action it's supposed to. In contrast, a call "does not block" if it somehow starts performing the action and returns the control to the caller while the action keeps running in the background. These latter methods usually rely on either accepting a callback to be run when the action is performed or by returning some form of handle that represents the "promise" that the action will be performed (sometime called a "future").

Comment: lovely explanation

Comment: Even after writing pyspark to a file we need to unpersist?